# Tune down JSHint for Play 2.3 : warnings instead of errors

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, sbt, jshint

I use Play 2.3.4 with the JShint sbt plugin. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/AssetsJSHint

I'd like to use JSHint to emit warnings and not errors in some cases.
How can I configure this to not break the compilation by emmitting an error, but stiell keep the warning

```
[error] /example.js:78: ['user_owner'] is better written in dot notation.
[error]         var x = a["user_owner"].toLowerCase();
[error]                  ^
       ^

[error] example.js:108: Unnecessary semicolon.
[error] };
[error]  ^
```

I allready read about `.jshintrc` but it looks like an on/off solution for me.

Comment: I suggest you add a feature request at: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jshint